# How to make a different React Native app out of existing app

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I have a React Native CLI project that can be built into an APK file. I need to amend the project and make a lite version of the this app. But, it needs to be a different app, meaning when I generate an APK file, it gets installed onto the same android device as a different app, without updating the existing one. Could you please tell me which files in my project folder I have to change and how to make this possible?

Comment: I changed defaultConfig in android/app/buidl.gradle, name in app.jason, name in strings.xml, name in package.json and it built me an apk file that installed different app, but, when I open it, I see an empty screen. It's like src folder with all the components are not hooked where they need to be hooked.

Comment: So, I changed the name of the app whereever I could find it. And it worked